# VusJS DOM update, when a a new value is selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, watch, vue-cli-3

I am trying to update DOM by the following logic but it's not working,

index.vue    [Template part]

```
<div>
     <div v-for="obj in objects" :key="obj.id">
           <select v-model="obj.quantity" @change="qtyChange(obj)">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

        <div class="w-1/5">
          <p class=" pt-4 text-right">${{ getObjectPrice(obj) }}</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

index.vue    [Script part]

```
  <script>
         props['selectedObjs'],
         data () {
               return {
                   objects: []
               }
         },
         mounted: {
                      this.objects = this.selectedObjs
                  },
         methods: {
                     getObjectPrice(obj)
                          {
                                // some mathematical calculations
                                // obj.quantity is used in multiplication
                                return answer
                          },

                     qtyChange(obj) {
                                   getObjectPrice(obj)
                     }
                  }
  </script>
```

I have tried to watch the objects data property but it is not working, I have to show the updated price of objects based on the quantity selected from the dropdown. if anyone can suggest me a good solution.

Comment: Can you show us your whole code?

Comment: No, I have just written the scenario that I have used. The code is private.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store selected value in local data. Then use it for calculation. And For calculation, better use `computed` rather `method`. In template print out your computed value.

Comment: we cannot pass a parameter to a computed property as much I know and it's mandatory for me to pass that object to do calculations.

Comment: reread once again what I write. if you don't trust me, then read [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)